# Why does Generic Algebraic Data Types require `T` on member types?

Tags: generics, kotlin

I want to define a Generic Algebraic Data Type for use with my `parse` function like this:

```
sealed class Result<T> {
    class Success(val value: T, val pos: Int) : Result<T>()
    class Failure(val message: String, val pos: Int) : Result<T>()
}

fun <T> parse(t: Parser<T>, input: String, initialPos: Int = 0, collectErrors: Boolean = true) : Result<T> {
```

However this is not allowed as `T` is then an undefined reference.

If I add `T` to all member types it works:

```
sealed class Result<T> {
    class Success<T>(val value: T, val pos: Int) : Result<T>()
    class Failure<T>(val message: String, val pos: Int) : Result<T>()
}
```

To me this is somewhat confusing which makes me believe I am missing something here. Why isn't `T` seen when defining the member types in the first case?

In addition when creating an instance of `Success` I would expect the syntax to be:

```
Result<T>.Success<T>(tv.someValue, pos)
```

But that won't work instead I do this:

```
Result.Success<T>(tv.someValue, pos)
```

This is the preferable syntax to me but I am struggling to understand why I should leave out `T` on Result here.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`Result` is a generic class, with a single generic parameter named T. The class name is `Result` though, not `Result<T>`.

`Success` is a generic class, too. So, since it's generic, you need to define it as `Success<T>`. If you don't, then it's not generic anymore. Note that, even though it's a subclass of Result which is generic, it could be a non-generic type. For example:

```
class Success(val value: String, val pos: Int) : Result<String>()
```

Also note that although Result and Failure are generic, they don't use their generic type for anything. So you could in fact define your classes as

```
sealed class Result {
    class Success<T>(val value: T, val pos: Int) : Result()
    class Failure(val message: String, val pos: Int) : Result()
}
```

Now, why do you need to use `Result.Success<T>(tv.someValue, pos)` and not `Result<T>.Success<T>(tv.someValue, pos)`?

Because the name of the class is `Result.Success`. The parameter type is not part of the class name. Most of the time, it's not necessary to specify it at all because it will be inferred:

```
val r = Result.Success("foo", 1)
```

creates an instance of `Success<String>`. If you wanted instead to create a `Success<CharSequence>`, then you would have to specify the generic type explicitly:

```
val r = Result.Success<CharSequence>("foo", 1)
```

or

```
val r: Result.Success<CharSequence> = Result.Success("foo", 1)
```

Comment: Thanks. I realized that `Result` strictly don't need to be generic but I like it to be because `parse` produces a `Result` which `Success<T>` generic type is the same as `Parser<T>`. If I would not include `T` in Result I (perhaps mistakenly) believe the API would be less type-safe.

Comment: What if I want a method signature like `fun foo(): Result<SomeType>`. So that the returned value is either a Success<SomeType> or Failure?

Answer (score 4):

The rules are the same as in Java. It basicly comes down to `Success` and `Failure` being static nested classes of `Result`. There are no "member types" in Kotlin, static nested classes are regular classes that have access to the scope of the outer class. And if a class extends a generic super class, it always needs to bind the generic type parameters.

In contrast, non-static nested classes (denoted by the `inner` keyword) always carry the generic type paremeter of the outer class. This way you can construct the following type hierarchy:

```
open class Foo<T> {
    inner class Bar : Foo<T>()
}
```

To instantiate `Bar` you will need to have an instance of `Foo`:

```
val b = Foo<String>().Bar()
```

Comment: Thanks. I am still somewhat puzzled why `T` isn't visible to the static inner classes as I would think `T` would be part of the scope.

Comment: I guess that's just how it works in Java and it works the same in Kotlin. Are you coming from a language where it works differently?

Comment: @FuleSnabel static nested classes (there is no such thing as a static inner class) are no different from top-level classes. The only difference is that they have a weirder name (Result.Success instead of Success), and that they can access the private members of their enclosing class (and vice-versa). Other than that, they're just like top-level classes. Inner classes are different, because they have an implicit reference to their owner **instance**.

Comment: I am comparing with my experience from `OCaml` like languages where I would declare an ADT somewhat like this: `type Result<'T> = Success of 'T*int | Failure of String*int`

Comment: Kotlin _could_ have made the syntax possible but I guess the designers decided it doesn't provide too much value. You need to remember that `sealed` classes are just regular abstract classes where all inheritors are known, nothing more.

Comment: Oh and as @JBNizet explains in his answer, you can have non-generic subclasses of a generic sealed class.

Answer (score 1):

It should work if you use the out variance like this,

```
sealed class Result<out T> {
  data class Success<out T>(val value: T, val pos: Int) : Result<T>()
  data class Failure(val message: String, val pos: Int) : Result<Nothing>()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your example there are three different generic parameters, not one. I.e. your code is equivalent to:

```
sealed class Result<I> {
    class Success<A>(val value: A, val pos: Int) : Result<A>()
    class Failure<B>(val message: String, val pos: Int) : Result<B>()
}
```

But how other answers mention, you do not use the `I` and `B` parameters, so they are better to be omitted.

Comment: The property `value` is of type `T`. Your code doesn't compile.